# Divide an array into smaller chunks, matching a certain range per array (minimum/maximum)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have some data like this:

```
var boxes = [
    {
        name: 'Box 1',
        weight: 2,
    },
    {
        name: 'Box 2',
        weight: 5,
    },
    {
       name: 'Box 3',
       weight: 4,
    },
    // Some more boxes
]
```

Is there some sort of function to split these `boxes` into smaller arrays, where you can define a minimum and maximum total weight per array? For example: divide the `boxes` into multiple arrays, where the total weight of each array is between 8-10, or return `false` if there isn't a possible way to divide them like that?

For example: with just the numbers / weights in mind, the result would look something like this:

```
// Boxes with weights 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1
[
    [7, 1], // Total: 8
    [6, 2], // Total: 8
    [5, 3], // Total: 8
    [5, 5], // Total: 10
    [5, 4], // Total: 9
    [4, 4]  // Total: 8
]
// Boxes with weights 5, 4, 5, 6, 7
[
    [5, 5], // Total: 10
    [4, 6], // Total: 10
    [7], // --> Total lower than minimum (8), function should return false
]
```

It's mostly finding the logic I find hard. There is a way I've had the most success with, although not 100% failproof. (Sometimes it would say a combination of the different weights, the minimum and maximum value is impossible, although it was):

- Sorting the boxes by weight in descending order
- Looping over the boxes, starting by the heaviest, and adding the lighter boxes (starting from the end) until I reach the minimum total weight (ex. 8). Each time I add a box to a smaller array, I remove it from larger array.

Comment: `I've been looking at this for hours` Have you made any attempt at writing code yet? Probably start there (if you have, please post what you've tried)

Comment: Any other requirements like e.g. keeping the initial order or getting an optimal result?

Comment: @aefxx keeping the initial order isn't a requirement, but it should indeed try to find the most optimal result. That way, when the function returns false, it is 100% certain that the combination of `boxes`, minimum value and maximum value is impossible.

Comment: This is a non-trivial algorithm you're asking for us to find, or write for you.  You need to show what you've tried, what research you've attempted, etc.  [ask]

Comment: There are too many conditions you didn't mentioned, no one can guess what you really expect, at least you could have tried to put an expected result, but you want the community to event think in your place... :-|

Comment: and please add to your try a data set to work with.

Comment: Take a look at this "Knapsack Problem" and solution: https://gist.github.com/lqt0223/21f033450a9d762ce8aee4da336363b1  it might give you a starting point.

Comment: The moment I read the question "NP-hard" popped up in my mind ^^

Comment: @trpnt Were you able to find any solution?